# Login Page is not navigating next page even after providing password validation

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have provided validations for email and password, but even after typing the password, its says "Password is required", So I don't know where I am going wrong. Please anyone help me because I am new to PHP as well as Codeigniter.

login.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');
        $this->load->model('Login_db');
        $login_form_options = array();
        // Validation.
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(array(
            array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required|valid_email',
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'required',
            ),
        ));
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->load->view('login_form', array(
                'login_form_options' => $login_form_options,
            ));
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Login_db');
            $login = new Login_db();
            $login->email = $this->input->post('email');
            $login->password = $this->input->post('password');
            $login->save();
            $this->load->view('login_form_success', array(
                'login' => $login,
            ));
        }
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');
    }

}
```

login_db.php

```
<?php

class Login_db extends MY_Model {

    const DB_TABLE = 'login';
    const DB_TABLE_PK = 'user_id';

    /**
     * Login unique identifier.
     * @var int
     */
    public $user_id;

    /**
     * Login email.
     * @var string
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * Login password.
     * @var string
     */
    public $password;

}
```

login_form.php

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="issue_number">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="Password" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

These are the problems when running the codes:
[output screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yszGu.png) 
[ouput screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ef6C.png)

The both email and password should get navigated to next page after typing.
Eg : Login Created (Page should be displayed).

Comment: Could you share the `Login_db` model and also the `login_form` view?

Comment: Hi, I have submitted login_db.php and login_form.php

Comment: What does `$this->Login_db->get()` means? why are you using uncommon methods on your code? also is this a registration page or a login verification page?

Comment: also you have the password rule set to `password` (all lowercase), while the field is set to `Password` (uppercase first character), perhaps that's why it didn't catch the 
password value

Comment: I have changed "password" to "Password", but still its not working

Comment: okay, so could you explain this line : `$logins = $this->Login_db->get();` ?

Comment: Now I have provided the edited codes and sorry for the previous codes. Its a Login Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `login_form.php` input `<input type="password" name="Password" value="">` name is in capital letter i.e. **Password** and in your `login.php` your validation set_rule array has a  `'field' => 'password'`. In this **password** in this password is small letter.

You can either change a input name attribute or set_rule array key.

Comment: @bhuvana you've said that changing "password" to "Password" doesn't work